# how to save objects stored in a list column in R

Tags: r, save, purrr

If I generate a list column of models and want to save all the models as .rda files I am running into some trouble.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mt_models <- 
    mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(
        models = map(.x = data, .f = ~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)),
        file_name = paste("model", cyl, "cyl.rda", sep = "_")
    ) 


# mt_models$models currently have no names
names(mt_models$models)

# so I've assigned names to the models so that save() will be handling named objects.
names(mt_models$models) <- paste("model", mt_models$cyl, "cyl", sep = "_")

walk2(
  .x = mt_models$models, 
  .y = mt_models$file_name,
  .f = ~save(.x, file = .y)
)
```

While I can see the saved objects in my directory, I cannot `load` the saved objects into my environment.

When I try to load, the function appears to run successfully, but nothing happens, not even an error, and no objects are added to my environment.

```
load("model_6_cyl.rda")
```

In contrast if I save one model it is readily viewable in my environment and easily loaded.

```
mt_model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

save(mt_model, file = "temp.rda")

load("temp.rda")
```

Comment: You can specify `list = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make some changes by `assign`ing to an object identifier and then `save`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
walk2(
  mt_models$models, 
  mt_models$file_name,

   ~   {nm1 <- str_remove(.y, "\\.rda")
       assign(nm1, .x)
       save(list = nm1, file = .y )
       }

)
```

On a fresh R session

```
ls()
#character(0)
load("model_6_cyl.rda")
ls()
#[1] "model_6_cyl"
```

`saveRDS` may be better though

Comment: I'm unclear on how to apply `list = ` in `walk()`. My attempt to add `list = ` to `walk()` is not working. 
`walk2(
  .x = mt_models$models, 
  .y = mt_models$file_name,
  .f = ~save(list = .x, file = .y)
)`

Comment: @Joe I updated the post.  Sorry, earlier I got busy

Answer (score 2):

The model gets loaded as `.x`, which is not displayed by `ls()` unless provided with `all.names=TRUE`:

```
# In a fresh R session
load("model_6_cyl.rda")
ls( all.names=TRUE )
# [1] ".x"
```

You can load all the models back in one sweep by encapsulating the loading inside a new environment, defined by `{}`, then returning `.x` from that environment:

```
mdls <- purrr::map( list.files(pattern="rda"), ~{load(.); .x} )
```